# Reason behind why the json format value in my table is changed when printed in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

The value inside my table looked like this

```
[{"lat":10.290508881982095,"lng":123.86115660890937},
{"lat":10.290656669572147,"lng":123.86174133047462},
{"lat":10.290482491333735,"lng":123.86191299185157},
{"lat":10.290007459285796,"lng":123.86215439066291}]`
```

but when i print it in laravel the table column name was in already included looked like this

```
[{"route":"[{\"lat\":10.290508881982095,\"lng\":123.86115660890937},
{\"lat\":10.290656669572147,\"lng\":123.86174133047462},
{\"lat\":10.290482491333735,\"lng\":123.86191299185157},
{\"lat\":10.290007459285796,\"lng\":123.86215439066291}]"}]
```

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: show us the code you use to print it?

Comment: {{ $setroute }}

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46080939/edit) additional information into the question description.

Comment: and how is `{{ $setroute }} ` filled?

Comment: i get the value inside my table sir

Comment: the way that i get the routes in json format is json.stringify();

Comment: how can i print it the same way like inside the table?

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is text.

> but when i print it in laravel the table column name was in already included

The second JSON from your question looks like it is the encoding of an array that contains an object having the first JSON as the value of its `route` property. Something like this:

```
$value = '... the first JSON posted in the question ...';
$resultset = array(
    (object)(array('route' => $value)
);

echo(json_encode($resultset));
```

The bottom line: the second JSON is the text representation of a data structure that contains another JSON (that itself is the text representation of another data structure). It is the result of double encoding as JSON.